# Top N record sort to return only the numbers that fall in particular range in the sorted array

Tags: c, arrays, algorithm, sorting

I have a hashtable that may contain around 1-5 million records. I need to iterate over it to select some of the entries in it and then sort them in some order. Also, I don't actually the need all the sorted elements, but say some elements that fall in a particular range. For eg. if the hashtable contains 1 million records, I may require only top 1000th-2000th records. Is there a standard sort algorithm for this? If not may be I can implement a 2 pass algorithm, first pass to find the 1000th record and say next pass to determine what next next 1000 records could be. Is there any implementation of heap sort available for this? Any implementation of topN heap sort would help for this too I guess. There is also a constraint on the size of the array I can use. It would be the best, if I have the array size to be only the number of records requested.

Comment: Why are you using a hashtable in the first place? Why not use a balanced tree of some sort?

Comment: hashtable is an already existing data which I need to use as input.. Cannot change that

Comment: Wait, one clarification: you need to get the elements by their *order* in the sorted array, not by a range criteria of the actual items?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a standard algorithm for this. As @Ivaylo Strandjev pointed out in his answer, quickselect is the typical way this is done. However, that will require O(n) extra space in this case because you can't rearrange the hash table.

The other way commonly used is a heap. If you want the 1000th to 2000th smallest items, you do it in two passes. First, you use the heap to find the 1000th smallest item. Then you do another pass to get the 1000 smallest items that are greater than or equal to the one you found in the first pass. Something like:

First pass:

```
h = new max heap
add first 1000 items to heap
for i = 1000 to n-1
    if hashtable[i] < heap.peek()
        heap.remove_first()
        heap.add(item)
```

The 1000th smallest item is now the largest item on the heap. So:

```
smallest = heap.remove_first()
```

Now make a new heap of size 1,000 and add that item. Then go through the list again and only add items that are >= smallest:

```
h = new max heap
for i = 0 to n-1
    if hashtable[i] >= smallest
        if heap.count < 1000
            heap.add(item)
        else if hashtable[i] < heap.peek()
            heap.remove_first()
            heap.add(item)
```

When you're done, the heap contains items 1000 to 2000.

One nice thing about this technique is that you can allocate a single array and manipulate it like a heap. See [Binary heap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_heap) for an overview, or check out my [series on heaps](http://blog.mischel.com/2013/12/18/posting-the-heap-code/). The first three articles explain the problem and provide enough information that you should be able to implement a simple heap in C. There is a code example in C# you can use as a starting point.

Remember, though, that I'm using a Max-heap in the example above. The discussions in my blog post is about Min-heap, so you'll have to be sure to change the comparisons accordingly.

Complexity of heap selection is O(n log k), where n is the size of the list and k is the number of items to be selected. If you want the items to be sorted when you return them in the array, you'll have to sort the heap (or remove the items one-by-one). In either case, that's O(k log k). So your total running time will be proportional to `(n log k) + (k log k)`.

Although quickselect is asymptotically faster than heap select, in practice heap select is generally faster than quickselect when you're selecting 1% or fewer of the items. So if you're selecting 1,000 items from a list of a million, heap selection will almost certainly be faster. See [When theory meets practice](http://blog.mischel.com/2011/10/25/when-theory-meets-practice/) for details.

### Update

As the OP pointed out in comments, this can require a rather large heap. For example if you want to find the 10,000th through 11,000th items, the first pass requires a heap of size 10,000. The second pass still requires only a heap of 1,000 items. Using the naive method, selecting the 990,000th through 999,000th items would require a heap of size 998,000. However, you could turn it around: use a Min-heap and then you'd only need a heap of size 1,000 again (i.e. find the 1,000th through 2,000th largest items). So the heap size you need for the first pass is `min(r1, (n-r2))`. The heap size required for the second pass is `r2 - r1`.

You *could* do it by creating a single heap of size `r2`. Do a pass to get the smallest `r2` items, and then select the top `r2-r1` items from that. It makes the complexity `(n log r2) + (k log r2)`. And `k` is equal to `r2-r1`. Again, you could use Min-heap to reduce your memory requirement if r1 > n/2.

I considered the possibility of doing this in a single pass with a Min-max heap, but I don't think it'll work.

Comment: But I have a doubt related to second pass. When we keep adding items greater than the smallest, how do we obtain just the exact next 1000 items. Suppose the list contains 4000 items, wouldn't 1000th item and rest 30002th to 4000th get selected?

Comment: Considering the above algorithm for the case when instead of 1000th-2000th, last thousand items from a total of say 1 million items are to be chosen. In the first pass, the heap size requirement would be actually quite large. Correct me if I am wrong. If this is true then  should a single pass algorithm be preferred. Suppose, we need items in range r1 to r2 (r2 > r1), then we always create a heap with size r2, perform sorting and then select only (r2-r1) elements. Would this work too?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the partitioning algorithm used in `quick sort`. The algorithm is known as 'quickselect' and it is utilized in `c++` implementation of `nth_element`. Using this approach you will be able to solve your problem in linear time. For more information you can refer to wikipedia's article on [quickselect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quickselect).

This algorithm gives you the ability to modify an input array in linear time so that all elements after position `n` are greater than the element at position n and all elements before it are smaller than the element at position `n`. Now let's assume you want to know which elements are in positions `A` to `B` in the array `a`. Then you first apply the algorithm once for position `B`. Thus all elements we are interested in are in the interval `[0,B]`. Now apply the algorithm once more this time only for the subarray ending at position B, with argument `A`. Now you will have all elements in the interval `[A,B]`. Note the elements will be in arbitrary order.

Comment: I actually could not relate to the algorithm mentioned on the link. Can you please elaborate a little more  and if possible, with some example! Thank you in advance :)

Comment: @labyrinth I do not understand what you mean by `I could not relate to the algorithm`

Comment: I meant that I could not relate how that problem could solve problem stated above

Comment: @labyrinth I have added more details. 
Hope this will help.

Comment: Thanks for making it clear. I now understand how this works. But I have another array size constraint. I cannot have all my records in the array. Thinking on the lines of using a heap sort kind thing but not sure how! Thanks for your help :)

Comment: @labyrinth if you are interested in the first `A` elements using a heap is the best approach. However this will not work if you are only interested in elements after `A` but before `B`. Still if `B` is relatively small you can first use heap to filter the first `B` elements in an array and then go with my approach.

Comment: But if this is a `O(n)` solution, then OP can simply iterate through all elements and copy the ones matching the criteria into the target array. And I doubt that rearranging the hash table is possible. And worst case performance for quickselect is `O(n^2)`.

Comment: @Groo the required criteria is to select Ath to Bth element in the sorted sequence and it can not be simply checked on each element. OP will need a helper array as rearanging a hash is as you state not possible.

Comment: Oh, right, the question title states this. Sorry for the mistake. In that case it's `O(n)` time and additional `O(n)` space as you said.